# How To Edit Product Fields in Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

**How To Edit Product Fields in Gravity Forms**

> Product fields are not editable

this is a issue when i try to edit the entry in gravity form..

is there anyway to edit that entry ??

I am adding the screen shot..

[image]

[image]

anyone have idea about this???

Answer (score 0):

I've written a snippet for this a while back. You can add a plugin header to this and run it as a plugin or use something like [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/).

https://gist.github.com/spivurno/416f1981e48bd3227e6b

Comment: can you suggest how to use it?

Comment: Just install the snippet and it will just work. When you go to edit the entries the products will be editable.

Answer (score 0):

(If you're using GravityView, an add-on, this is pretty easy.)

GravityView supports editing Product fields (added in Version 1.20).
https://docs.gravityview.co/article/406-editing-product-and-pricing-fields

`/** Force showing product fields in the Edit Entry editor. */
add_filter( 'gravityview/edit_entry/hide-product-fields', '__return_false' );`